# Remove part of a string throughout a column

Tags: vba, excel

I have this data on column A:

```
/importantThing1/importantThing2/
/unimportantThing/importantThing1/importantThing2
/unimportantThing/importantThing/importantThing2
/importantThing1/importantThing4/importantThing5
```

And I want it to look like this:

```
/importantThing1/importantThing2/
/importantThing1/importantThing2
/importantThing/importantThing2
/importantThing1/importantThing4/importantThing5
```

The `"unimportantThing"` is always the same.
I tried some formulas but they didn't work because not all the cells contain the `"unimportantThing"`. I would like to do this using VBA. Please help!

Answer (score 0):

Just use the `Replace` function to replace `"/unimportantThing"` with an empty string (`""`):

```
Columns("A:A").Replace "/unimportantThing", ""
```